# Django model with filterable attributes

Tags: python, sql, mysql, django, django-models

I've got two models. One represents a piece of equipment, the other represents a possible attribute the equipment has. Semantically, this might look like:

- Equipment: `tractor`, Attributes: `wheels`, `towing`
- Equipment: `lawnmower`, Attributes: `wheels`, `blades`
- Equipment: `hedgetrimmer`, Attributes: `blades`

I want to make queries like,

```
wheels = Attributes.objects.get(name='wheels')
blades = Attributes.objects.get(name='blades')

Equipment.objects.filter(has_attribute=wheels) \
    .exclude(has_attribute=blades)
```

**How can I create Django models to do this?**

This seems simple, but I'm just too dense to see the right solution.

One solution that popped into my head is to encode the list of `Attribute` IDs in an integer list like `|109|14|3` and test for attributes using `Equipment.objects.filter(attributes_contains='|%d|' % id)` -- but this seems really wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is pretty close, but you need to understand how the [QuerySet API works across relationships (i.e. joins)](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Equipment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute)

equips = Equipment.objects.filter(
    attributes__name='wheels').exclude(attributes__name='blades')
```

You can use Q objects in your QuerySet to do more interesting queries.

And keep in mind you can always dump the SQL from a QuerySet like this:

```
print equips.query.as_sql()
```

Sometimes you'll want to see the exact SQL being generated to make sure you're using the API correctly.